# Reference for shloka related to qualities of soul - Chin matram shreehareer ansham sookshma akshar

Tags: vedas, puranas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

Trying to find the reference for shloka:

> Chin matram shreehareer ansham sookshma akshar avyayam
> Krishna bhi nit prabhu jeevan gyan guna advayam

> चिन मात्रं श्रीहरेर अंशं सूक्ष्म अक्षर अव्ययं
> कृष्णा भी नित प्राभु जीवं ज्ञान गुणा अद्वयं

potential meaning of the words
Certainly! Here's the meaning of each word in the provided verse:

1. चिन (Chin) - Recognize
2. मात्रं (Matram) - Only
3. श्रीहरेर (Shreehareer) - Of Lord Shrihari (a name for Lord Vishnu or Krishna)
4. अंशं (Ansham) - Part
5. सूक्ष्म (Sookshma) - Subtle
6. अक्षर (Akshar) - Imperishable
7. अव्ययं (Avyayam) - Immutable
8. कृष्णा (Krishna) - Referring to Lord Krishna
9. भी (Bhi) - Also
10. नित (Nit) - Always
11. प्राभु (Prabhu) - Lord
12. जीवं (Jeevan) - Life
13. ज्ञान (Gyan) - Knowledge
14. गुणा (Guna) - Attributes or qualities
15. अद्वयं (Advayam) - Non-dual, without a second

Does anyone know from where this shloka is ?

Comment: Where did you read this śloka?